# Pandas DataFrame apply function doubling size of DataFrame

Tags: python, function, pandas, apply

I have a Pandas DataFrame with numeric data. For each non-binary column, I want to identify the values larger than its 99th percentile and create a boolean mask that I will later use to remove the rows with outliers.

I am trying to create this boolean mask using the `apply` method, where `df` is a DataFrame with numeric data of size *a***b*, as follows.

```
def make_mask(s):
    if s.unique().shape[0] == 2: # If binary, return all-false mask
        return pd.Series(np.zeros(s.shape[0]), dtype=bool)
    else: # Otherwise, identify outliers
        return s >= np.percentile(s, 99)

s_bool = df.apply(make_mask, axis=1)
```

Unfortunately, `s_bool` is output as a DataFrame with twice as many columns (i.e., size *a***(b**2)). The first *b* columns are named 1, 2, 3, etc. and are full of null values. The second *b* columns seem to be the intended mask.

**Why is the `apply` method doubling the size of the DataFrame?** Unfortunately, the Pandas [apply documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) does not offer helpful clues.

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct code?  `raw=True` means that the function is passed an `ndarray`, and `ndarray` objects don't have a `unique` method.  I tried it with `raw=False` and it worked fine.

Comment: My bad, the `raw` argument should not be specified so that it is set as `False` implicitly. The doubling of the columns occurs when I do not set this argument at all.

Comment: I tried the new version with a random DataFrame and couldn't reproduce the problem: `df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((50,20)), columns=tuple('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[:20]), index=np.arange(0,5,.1))`

Comment: Could you edit the question to include instructions on how to create a sample `DataFrame` that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Definitely, let me take a look at that. I'm currently using Pandas version `0.16.0`, which seems to be the latest.

Comment: That is the version I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear on why, but it seems the problem is that you are returning a series.  This seems to work in your given example:

```
def make_mask(s):
    if s.unique().shape[0] == 2: # If binary, return all-false mask
        return np.zeros(s.shape[0], dtype=bool)
    else: # Otherwise, identify outliers
        return s >= np.percentile(s, 99)
```

You can further simplify the code like so, and use `raw=True`:

```
def make_mask(s):
    if np.unique(s).size == 2: # If binary, return all-false mask
        return np.zeros_like(s, dtype=bool)
    else: # Otherwise, identify outliers
        return s >= np.percentile(s, 99)
```

Comment: This also solves the problem with my original data. Thank you!